# Stuck on xcode files

Tags: xcode

I have downloaded the xcode 12.5.xip file and expanded it on the desktop of my Mac. But it is the virtual "Desktop" on iCloud.

Apparently I should have moved the zip file to the Programs directory first, but unfortunately, I did not.

I have several problems:

1. Trying to delete the zip file seems to take forever.
2. Or trying to move the zip file to the Programs directory starts the spinning ball, and I can't do anything but force close my Mac.
3. If I try moving the expanded Xcode app (also residing on the virtual desktop), the spinning ball also pops up, and I have to force close my Mac.

I read that I could use Terminal to delete the file(s), but since the reside on iCloud rather than my Mac, I don't think that will work. In any case, I can't find the path.

The two files are each about 12GB.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2017/07/06/disable-icloud-desktop-documents-mac/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look into if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem is different: Even copying or moving small files crashes my Mac. The spinner starts rotating until I force close the Mac.

So I guess that I need to make a clean install of my Mac. Annoying and time consuming, but doable.

Thanks anyway, guys.

EDIT - The day after:
Now all of sudden the problem seems to have corrected itself. After one night, I could do those normal deletions and movings again.

Weird.